# lambda multipart/file upload in go

Tags: go, file-upload, aws-lambda

I need to do some simple manipulation with the content of the uploaded file uploaded through AWS Lambda using Go, but not sure how to parse the receiving content since I'm new to Go. The solutions that I've found so far are related to http package and MultiPart form function.

```
type Request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest

func Handler(ctx context.Context, req Request) (Response, error) {
fmt.Println(req.Body)
....
}
```

This is how my request body looks like

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryx0SVDelfa90Fi5Uo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="upload.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

this is content

------WebKitFormBoundaryx0SVDelfa90Fi5Uo--
```

my request is instance of `APIGatewayProxyRequest`.

I would like to know if it is possible to get a custom struct from which I can access data like f.e.

```
customStruct.content => "this is content"
customStruct.fileName => upload.txt
customStruct.fileExtension => txt
```

Comment: You haven't given much information about what you need help with.
Would the strings package help you (e.g. for `strings.Split()` or for `strings.Index()`)? 
https://pkg.go.dev/strings

Comment: understand, my actual question would be is there an option to parse the content in the body in way so that I can get a struct from which I can do something like
```
fileStruct.content
fileStruct.fileName
fileStruct.fileFormat
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#NewReader

Comment: if you read the standard api, https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/net/http/request.go;l=1311,  they call for https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/mime/multipart/formdata.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.16.6;l=30 that should do it to reproduce this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 parts to this:

1. create a `multipart.Reader` from `events.APIGatewayProxyRequest`
2. get the MIME Part
3. extract MIME Part values

### Step 1: Create a `multipart.Reader`

The `multipart.NewReader` takes an `io.Reader` and `boundary` string as shown by the signature:

```golang
func NewReader(r io.Reader, boundary string) *Reader
```

To do this, you will need to extract the boundary string from the `Content-Type` HTTP request header which can be done using `mime.ParseMediaType`.

An easy way to do this is to call `NewReaderMultipart` from the [`go-awslambda`](https://github.com/grokify/go-awslambda) package which has the following signature:

```golang
func NewReaderMultipart(req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (*multipart.Reader, error)
```

### Step 2: get the MIME Part

Once you have the `mime.Reader`, navigate the MIME message till you find the MIME part desired.

In the example here, there's only one part, so you can simply call:

```golang
part, err := reader.NextPart()
```

### Step 3: Extract MIME part values

Once you have the MIME Part, the desired values can be extracted.

#### Step 3.1: Content

```golang
content, err := io.ReadAll(part)
```

#### Step 3.2: File name

Get the file name from the MIME part as follows:

```golang
filename := part.FileName()
```

#### Step 3.3: File extension

Call `path/filepath.Ext`. This will add the leading period `.` in the extension but this can be easily removed.

```golang
ext := filepath.Ext(part.FileName())
```

#### Summary

You can combine this as follows:

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/grokify/go-awslambda"
)

type customStruct struct {
    Content       string
    FileName      string
    FileExtension string
}

func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    res := events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}
    r, err := awslambda.NewReaderMultipart(req)
    if err != nil {
        return res, err
    }
    part, err := r.NextPart()
    if err != nil {
        return res, err
    }
    content, err := io.ReadAll(part)
    if err != nil {
        return res, err
    }
    custom := customStruct{
        Content:       string(content),
        FileName:      part.FileName(),
        FileExtension: filepath.Ext(part.FileName())}

    customBytes, err := json.Marshal(custom)
    if err != nil {
        return res, err
    }

    res = events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        Body: string(customBytes)}
    return res, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've actually tried the approach before, but instead of creating `NewReaderMultipart` I've tried creating the buffer that I would pass in to `NewReader` which was allowed bu compiler but would return me nil as return value every time. My temp solution was base64 encoding of the file before it being sent to the lambda

Answer (score 2):

The answer above looks to be the **correct** way to do that, but if you are lazy (as I am :p ) you can just create an HTTP request, and let the native lib work to you:

```golang
httpReq, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, req.HTTPMethod, reqURL.String(), strings.NewReader(req.Body))
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.New("failed to convert a lambda req into a http req")
}

// some headers may be important, let get all of them, just in case
for name, value := range req.Headers {
    httpReq.Header.Add(name, value)
}


// from here you can use httpReq.FormFile() to read the file
```